# Peut-on utiliser le présent pour une action au futur ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, futur

Je voudrais savoir si c'est possible d'utiliser le présent sur une action au futur:

> Exemple 1 :
>      Lorsque tu termines ton rapport tu me l'envoies
>
> Exemple 2 :
>      Lorsque tu termineras ton rapport tu me l'enverras

J'aimerais bien savoir quel exemple est juste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'exemple 1 est correct, mais plutôt à l'oral. Du coup, on utiliserait plutôt "quand" ou "dès que" plutôt que "lorsque" qui est un peu plus soutenu. L'exemple 2 est un peu maladroit : on utiliserait le futur antérieur "quand tu auras terminé ton rapport, tu me l'enverras".

D'ailleurs, dans l'exemple 1, on utiliserait souvent le passé composé pour la première action. Terminer le rapport se fait normalement avant de l'envoyer, un temps passé est donc utilisé pour indiquer cette contrainte. Mais à part ça, à l'oral du moins, on utilise volontiers le présent pour une action au futur.
Les formules suivantes seraient un peu plus correctes :

> Tu termines ton rapport et tu me l'envoies. *(oral)*
>
> Dès que tu as terminé ton rapport, tu me l'envoies. *(oral)*
>
> Lorsque tu auras terminé ton rapport, tu me l'enverras.

PS : ces exemples sont plus ou moins impératifs, mais le présent s'utilise plus volontiers dans un contexte plus indicatif :

> Je finis mon rapport et je te l'envoie.
>
> J'arrive dans deux minutes.
>
> L'année prochaine, je passe en terminale.

Comment: Merci beaucoup c'est noté vos remarques, une petite question c'est quoi le plus du `Futur antérieur` dans une phrase ?

Comment: Le futur antérieur marque le "passé dans le futur". On l'utilise pour des faits qui n'ont pas encore eu lieu, mais auront lieu avant les autres évènements dont il est question. Le rapport n'est pas encore terminé, mais finir le rapport se produira avant de le rendre, donc du point de vue de l'action "envoyer le rapport", l'action "terminer le rapport" est dans le passé.